# What is the difference between RewriteRule ^ index.php and RewriteRule . index.php and

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php
```

and

```
RewriteRule . index.php
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php
```

?

Is there any difference in operation of these rules?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php
```

Matches any URL

```
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Matches any URL at least one character long (in practice, because this includes `/`, matches all URLs).

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php
```

Matches ONLY `/` and the empty string. The `^` matches the start of the URL, `/?` matches an optional `/`, and `$` matches the end of the URL. So, the only possible matches are a URL consisting of no characters and one consisting of exactly `/`.

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php
```

Matches any URL.